# Change multiple elements by id at the same time with directive?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a mobile site where with the click of a button I need to change the css styling of 5 or 6 differently id'd divs.  I'm basically moving some of them around / changing their height and z-index, etc.

I've got it all working by doing like this in the controller in a function:

```js
document.getElementById("div1").style.height = "46px";
document.getElementById("div2").style.height = "46px";
document.getElementById("div3").style.margin = "94px";
document.getElementById("div4").style.top = "97px";
document.getElementById("div5").style.zIndex = "1";
```

And then later in another function, another click will set them all back by calling all of the above again with different values.

It all works as I want, but I know the controller is not the place for this kind of thing.

How would I use a directive to affect all these changes dynamically in the existing (relatively large) html template file?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of changing the styles from JavaScript, I would just change the model, and use templating (`style={{ }}`, or `ng-style="..."` or `ng-class="..."`) so that the elements update themselves based on what the model contains. That's basically how Angular is supposed to be used.

Comment: I already thought of that, but it seems very inelegant to put ng-class="..." conditionals in perhaps dozens of places.  Not to mention, I want to target the elements by their id.